# Variable not expanding inside curl command in linux

Tags: linux, curl

I have a curl command which I want to execute from inside a shell script.
My script is as below:

```
iddn="`jq -r '.APPID_DN' /scr/resp.json`"
appid = `echo "$iddn" | awk -F',' '{print $1}'`
id =`echo $appid | awk '{print substr($0,4)}'`
apppwd = `jq -r '.APPID_PWD' /scr/resp.json`
tnname = `jq '.tnName' /scr/resp.json`

curl -i --user "$id":"$apppwd" -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "X-USER-IDENTITY-DOMAIN-NAME: tn11" --request GET "http://hostname.XX.XXXX.com:port/XXX/services/rest/version/auth/administrator/Clients"
```

But I am getting below error
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Not authorized. Provide Authorization Header.

I tried by echoing the command to see how the curl command is forming,I am getting it as(userid and passwd not passed at all),

```
curl -i --user  -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "X-USER-IDENTITY-DOMAIN-NAME: tn11" --request GET "http://hostname.XX.XXXX.com:port/XXX/services/rest/version/auth/administrator/Clients"
```

But if i am running the same command directly from command line,its running fine.Please help on this.

Regards,
Shilpi

Comment: `echo  $id`, and so on... from there, just trace back where the problem came from.

Comment: "I tried by echoing" - and what happened to the `:`? ..:/

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32273446/encode-url-variable-with-curl
Sadly, I could not test it yet

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> id =`echo $appid | awk '{print substr($0,4)}'`
> apppwd = `jq -r '.APPID_PWD' /scr/resp.json`
> ```

You must not put spaces around `=` in a shell variable assignment.