# Encode URL variable with curl

Tags: linux, bash, curl

I have a rest endpoint that looks like this **http://someurl.com/{some_id}**

I need to be able to make a GET request to that using the curl command from linux, and I need to be able to send the variable url encoded

if I try 
`curl -G -v  'http://someurl.com' --data-urlencode 's*9678&as'` it adds the ? in front, I want to be able to send the "some_id" as part of the path

Comment: You need to URL encode that data string and use it in the URL directly? That's not what `--data-urlencode` is for. You are probably going to need to URL encode the data yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use `urlencode`.
If on ubuntu

```
$ sudo apt-get install gridsite-clients
```

then

```
$ curl -G -v  "http://someurl.com/$(urlencode 's*9678&as')"
```

Comment: That would work great,  I was hopping I can do it without installing stuff,  should work on stock Linux and mac

Comment: You can always compile it, or if python, perl, awk or node are available write your own version. Speaking about `awk` this may work: https://gist.github.com/moyashi/4063894

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano so, urlencode puts the part in the single quotes at the position of $ in the URL, right? Can I also pass a shell script variable to urlencode?

Comment: `$(cmd)` is replaced by the output of `cmd`. You can use vars, like `urlencode "$var"`.